# Convert String to custom array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have problem in my function php . 
My function php is to check coordinates whether the coordinates are in polygons .
the problem is , i call polygon latlong from database and type data is string and convert to custom array .

this my function

```
function containsMaps($point1,$value1)
{   
    $point = preg_split ("/\,/", $point1);  


    $value = $value1;

    foreach(explode('),(',trim($value,'()')) as $single_array){

        $sub_array= array();
        foreach(explode(',',$single_array) as $sbs_array)
        {
        $sub_array = array($sbs_array);
        }
        $polygon = array($sub_array);
      }



    if($polygon[0] != $polygon[count($polygon)-1])
        $polygon[count($polygon)] = $polygon[0];
    $j = 0;
    $oddNodes = false;
    $x = $point[1];
    $y = $point[0];
    $n = count($polygon);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
    {
        $j++;
        if ($j == $n)
        {
            $j = 0;
        }
        if ((($polygon[$i][0] < $y) && ($polygon[$j][0] >= $y)) || (($polygon[$j][0] < $y) && ($polygon[$i][0] >=
            $y)))
        {
            if ($polygon[$i][1] + ($y - $polygon[$i][0]) / ($polygon[$j][0] - $polygon[$i][0]) * ($polygon[$j][1] -
                $polygon[$i][1]) < $x)
            {
                $oddNodes = !$oddNodes;
            }
        }
    }
    return $oddNodes;
}
```

the polygon data from database like this :

(-6.268649975971238, 106.69106266990389),(-6.267711482694832, 106.72625325217928),(-6.288272630052733, 106.72736905112947),(-6.288699201273463, 106.69106266990389)

if i use static data like this , the function working :

```
$polygon = array(
        array(-6.2811957386588855, 106.70141951079609),
        array(-6.281142416506361, 106.70432702536823),
        array(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70438066954853),
        array(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70136586661579),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to split the incoming data isn't quite right. This will work:

```
foreach(explode('),(',trim($value,'()')) as $single_array){
    $polygon[] = explode(',',$single_array);
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '-6.268649975971238',
    1 => ' 106.69106266990389',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '-6.267711482694832',
    1 => ' 106.72625325217928',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '-6.288272630052733',
    1 => ' 106.72736905112947',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '-6.288699201273463',
    1 => ' 106.69106266990389',
  ),
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UPK4f)

Note this will give you string values, if you want floating point values, use code like this:

```
foreach(explode('),(',trim($value,'()')) as $single_array){
    list ($x, $y) = explode(',',$single_array); 
    $polygon[] = array((double)$x, (double)$y);
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/C2ksu)

Comment: how to remove ' in array ? because my function to compare coordinate with polygon not working ?

Comment: @Zaboy the `'` just indicate that the value is a string. However, comparing it to a number will cause the value to be converted to a number for comparison. So that shouldn't be an issue. It's more likely you're running into floating point precision issues...

Comment: You might want to try `list ($x, $y) = explode(',',$single_array); $polygon[] = array((double)$x, (double)$y);` but I think you probably need something like [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) to make this work.

Comment: can you help me , show the code to remove ' ' in array .

Comment: @Zaboy see my edit using the code from the previous comment and the new demo https://3v4l.org/C2ksu